# Open website with Basic authentication by asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I want to open a website on a button click of asp.net web page. The website  have basic authentication to open. I am using following code but its not the desired code to open website.

```
    CredentialCache credentialCache = new CredentialCache();
    NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential("uid", "pwd", "domain");
    credentialCache.Add(new Uri("https://www.abc.com"), "Basic", credentials);
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.abc.com");
    request.Credentials = credentialCache;

    HttpWebResponse res1 = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    using (HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        string ss = res.ResponseUri.ToString();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream());
        Response.Write (sr.ReadToEnd());

    }
```

`Response.Write` write the html of the requested page on my page but I need to redirect to that page to access the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long search and R & D finally i got the solution of this problem. We need to add the reference of a COM Component Microsoft Internet Controls i.e.  using SHDocVw;

When we try to open any website which requires the basic authentication then server respond with "HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized\r\n" and requires the client credentials and sends the header "www_authenticate" to the client when any browser recieve this header then its open the pop up box to insert the client credentials and we pass the client credentials to the server. Then server allows to access the application.

If we pass the client credentials on the first request to the server then it allows to access the application and don't requires the client credentials.

I have passed the client credentials with the following code .

```
InternetExplorer IEControl = new InternetExplorer(); 
        IWebBrowserApp webBrowserCtl = (IWebBrowserApp)IEControl; 
        string strUserName = "UserName"; 
        string strPassword = "Password"; 
        string strAuthenticationHeader = "Authorization: Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(strUserName + ":" + strPassword)) + "\r\n"; 
        webBrowserCtl.Visible = true; 
        webBrowserCtl.Navigate("http://www.abc.com/Home.aspx", null, null, null, strAuthenticationHeader);
```

Thanks

Rahul Pratap Singh